# Extend evaluation timeout length in variable quick watch in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Does anyone know how to change the length of the "quick watch" evaluation timeout in Visual Studio 2022? I have a huge data structure. I don't care if I have to wait a few minutes, I just want to let it run. This is for debugging. How do I increase the timeout length?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The request has been made before.
Please vote on related thread:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-a-setting-for-debugger-watch-timeout/1512470